# Omit scope parameter from form submission

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

I have two views with a shared controller and shared field definitions. I have set a default value for one of the input elements. This element, however, only renders for the Disburse action, at https://localhost:8449/my-app/#/loanaccount/15/disburse.

The Approve action renders at https://localhost:8449/my-app/#/loanaccount/15/approve. When I submit the form for Approve I'm getting a validation error `" The parameter checkNumber has been passed and is not supported for this request"`. It appears the Approve stage also implicitly submits the additional element from Disburse.

I want to omit submission of this scope parameter, but only for the Approve stage. In my controller I have:

```
 switch (scope.action) {
   case "disburse":                              
     resourceFactory.loanTrxnsTemplateResource.get({
       loanId: scope.accountId, 
       command: 'disburse'
     }, function (data) {
       scope.formData.checkNumber="USD"; 
     });
   case "approve":
     scope.taskPermissionName = 'APPROVE_LOAN';
     resourceFactory.loanTemplateResource.get({
       loanId: scope.accountId, 
       templateType: 'approval'
     }, function (data) {
       scope.formData.checkNumber= null;
     });
 }
```

Any pointers on how I can exclude submission of this scope parameter for the Approve stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this issue.

1) You can generate an another object with valid parameters and send the clean request.

2) OR You can delete the unwanted parameter, just like this.

```
delete scope.formData['checkNumber'];
```

But sometimes this would lead to a problem because form reference occurs.

3) OR Alternate the 'Approve rule' to only validate the requierd parameters and ignore (**Don't send back any exception / error**) if any unwanted parameter presented in the request.